# How do I turn this into a one line generator?

Tags: python

My best attempts have failed:

```
for s in self.services:
  for m in s.messages: yield m
```

Comment: @Oscar Python does not let you put two suite-introducers (for lack of a better term) on the same line like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`itertools.chain.from_iterable(s.messages for s in self.services)`

Comment: This is my favorite. Flat is better than nested, especially in one-liners.

Comment: Yes this is perfect - I wanted to use itertools.chain() as it was because I was doing multiple yields, so I just got more for the import.

Comment: @Tony: Do you realize that this will be perfectly incomprehensible to folks asked to maintain your code?  Are you aware that people will hate you for putting this into the code they must maintain?

Comment: I think the "nested" generator expression provided by Karl is much more immediately comprehensible than this solution. Even if it takes you a few seconds to work through the confusing (to me, anyway) syntax for nested comprehensions, it's at least obvious that it's a nested loop.  This, on the other hand, requires much more thought.

Comment: Well, I don't think anyone should have a problem guessing what a function called `itertools.chain` does, but at least you can just look it up otherwise. The double loop expression (or whatever you want to call it) looks way more confusing to me and its much harder to find out what it does.

Comment: The initial double `for` loop in the question seemed so crystal clear that I couldn't see any reason for attempting to improve it.  The question is a bad one to begin with.  This may be the least bad answer, but replacing a simple nested loop with this seems like an EPIC FAIL waiting to happen.

Answer (score 7):

`(m for s in self.services for m in s.messages)`

... as counter-intuitive as it seems.

Comment: This is based off an example found in PEP 289 which specifies (proposes?) generator expressions in the first place. The PEP doesn't really explain very well how it works in tricky cases like this; maybe it's depending on familiarity with this behaviour from list comprehensions?

Comment: Thanks, it does work, but I do like the itertools method as it is much easier to write and come back later and comprehend what is happening quickly.

Comment: I like the itertools method too. ;)

Comment: However, this method compiles to straight bytecode with no function calls.

Comment: I love this!! Especially for older versions of python where chain.from_iterable is not available.